# Differentiate $xx^T$ wrt to $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: derivatives

The problem is to find gradient and hessian of: $f(x) = \frac 1 2 || xx^T -A||_F^2$  given $A \in \mathbb{R^{n \times n}}$, $A$ is symmetric, $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
Notation:  $||\cdot||_F$ is a Frobenius norm of a matrix.

My progress with problem halted after the application of chain rule: no matter the transformation I make, the inner function contains $\frac  {\partial} {\partial x} xx^T$.

That is three dimensional object and to the best of my knowledge a matrix differentiation with respect to a vector is generally avoided.

I believe task requires to work around it, but I don't see a way.

Comment: What does the subscript $F$ stand for?

Comment: @uniquesolution Its frobenius norm; I have made an edit

Answer (score 2):

Define a new matrix variable
$$\eqalign{
Y &= xx^T-A \cr
dY &= dx\,x^T + x\,dx^T \cr
}$$
Then write the function in terms of this new variable, and find its differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
 f &= \frac{1}{2}Y:Y \cr
df &=Y:dY = Y:(dx\,x^T + x\,dx^T) \cr
   &= (Y+Y^T):dx\,x^T \cr
   &= 2Yx:dx \cr
 g = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= 2Yx \cr
}$$
Now find the differential and gradient of the gradient (i.e the Hessian)
$$\eqalign{
dg
 &= 2\,dY\,x + 2Y\,dx \cr
 &= 2\,(dx\,x^T + x\,dx^T)\,x + 2Y\,dx \cr
 &= 2\Big((x^Tx)I + xx^T +Y\Big)\,dx \cr
H = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}
 &= 2\Big((x^Tx)I + xx^T +Y\Big) \cr\cr
}$$
In some of these steps, a colon is used to denote the trace/Frobenius product 
$$A:B = {\rm tr}(A^TB)$$

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why,but in textbook *Matrix Algebra Theory computations and applications in statistics*, The derivatives of $xx^T$ with respect to $x$ is $2x^T$ on page154,hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It was true, the workaround was to use a trace property $x^Tx = Tr(xx^T)$

$df(x) = \frac 1 2 d\ Tr[(xx^T -A)^T(xx^T -A)]=
\frac 1 2 d\ Tr[ \cdot xx^T -xx^TA -Axx^T + A^2] = 
\frac 1 2 d[(x^Tx)^2 -2 x^Tx\ Tr(A)] = 
x^Tx \cdot x^Tdx - 2Tr(A)x^Tdx$
$\nabla f(x) = x^Txx - 2Tr(A)x$

$d^2(x) = d[x^Tx \cdot x^Tdx_1 - 2Tr(A)x^Tdx_1] = 
2x^Tdx_2 \cdot x^Tdx_1 + x^Tx \cdot dx_2^Tdx_1 - 2Tr(A)dx_2^Tdx_1 =$
$2dx_2^Tx \cdot x^Tdx_1 + x^Tx \cdot dx_2^Tdx_1 - 2Tr(A)dx_2^Tdx_1$
$\nabla^2f(x) = xx^T + (x^Tx - 2Tr(A)) \cdot I$